# Technology brain implant movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I only remember the following scenes:

1. A man on his laptop with a group of other men (he is the leader). They are watching an Eye-Cam of a man that is going into some kind of whorehouse, where the female bartender creates a drink called "Fuck Em". She makes the man drink it and kills him with some kind of poison within the drink. Once this has happened, the man watching on the laptop shuts everything down, throws hard-drives etc into a basket to light on fire, drops it on his way down the stairs and runs into some girl.
2. Later, the man that was on his laptop is now sitting down at this table with another man. The laptop man is dressed in a typical business type matter but casual clothes, clean, and neat. The other man is scruffy, in a lumberjack coat.  The laptop man is trying to get a confession from this other man, but the lumberjack coat man is not *really* the man he is after. He has a brain chip that was implanted into him from some hi-tech company, which has created a copy of himself within a piece of device.  They recreated a scenario where the lumberjack coat man was in his lover's house, where the lovers father lived. There, he killed the father with a blow to the head with some kind of object.
3. Finally, there is this woman that is sitting in a hospital bed, probably at the hi-tech facility, getting her brain chip extracted from her body.  She will be hiring the chip as a personal slave, example; to open blinds, make toast, coffee, anything the real woman wanted.  Once she goes under for surgery, her brain chip is still active, freaking out and wondering why is "it" still awake, while the audience hears some kind of extraction going on within a body, broken bones and sawing and such. It gets pulled out and set down onto a platform and gets shut off by the surgeon. It turns back on about 4 seconds later to the laptop man, the laptop man put this brain chip into what he (his company) calls a cookie. The brain chip woman is freaking out in this white bio-dome that she was generated in, stuck in a white room with only a desk with a console on it (touch screen block looking screen). The laptop man is explaining to the confused brain chip generated woman that the real her didn't want "it" anymore, and that "it" is not the real her, and that "it" will be it's personal slave.  The brain chip generated woman starts to freak out even more, then the laptop man sends her on a generated 1 month isolation, and then 6 months right after that -making her beg to work instead of being kept in isolation.

Answer (score 11):

What you are looking for is not actually a movie. It is Episode 1 of season 3 (or Internet movie database says season 2 ep 4 and wiki says episode 7 and it is also known as a "Christmas Special") depending on location, of the sci-fi/dystopian series called  [Black Mirror](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2085059/) ["White Christmas"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3973198/).

This episode stars Jon Hamm as the laptop man, Natalia Tena as the "f you drink girl" and Rafe Spall as the lumberjack.

The woman in hospital who has a personal slave, the guy who was the leader of the group on the laptop during the "whorehouse" part and later in the cabin with the "lumberjack"are all 3 plot points within this 1 single episode of the [series, Black Mirror.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2085059/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

[image] [image]
[image]